# How would I convert decimal years in to years and days

Tags: python, date, python-3.x, data-conversion

Say that I have a decimal that looks like this `5.08493150685` remembering that the very first number in that string being a 5, which is that number of years. So my question is how would I convert the `.08493150685` in the number of days. **Expect result: 5 years and 31 days**. (This is just an example.)

Comment: I thought 60/365 would give ~0.16

Comment: Fractional years are not a good idea because years vary in length. In your example, the result would be different depending on whether or not year `5` is a leap year. And I'm not even considering leap *seconds*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Is there a way to get around that problem???

Comment: @Alex, yup, do like everyone else and measure time in seconds, not years. As a bonus, it will make your code portable to other planets / solar systems.

Comment: @Alex if you really have to use years, try basing it off UTC

Comment: Thanks for all of the really good feedback :-)

Comment: No only do years have different lengths, it depends on when and where they are occurring, the rules vary. Even if you knew this, it would be a complex algorithm since for larger whole year values like 2541, there would be a mixture of leap and non-leap years — and once they even left out a bunch of days to correct the calendar. Fairly messy problem unless you make a lot of assumptions and do it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as it just a rough estimate, you can take the average year with 365.25 days. This would be a way to get years and days:

```
>>> years, year_fraction = divmod(5.08493150685, 1)
>> days = round(year_fraction * 365.25)
>>> years
5
>>> days
31
```

### Update

365.25 days per year is pretty coarse. As @martineau suggests in his comment, [365.2425 would be a better number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year). This takes into account that full centuries are not leap year except if they are divisible by 400.

Comment: Might was well go for the gusto and use `365.2425` days which is closer to the average year length (due to the occasional skipping of leap years).

Answer (score 2):

Not every year is the same length. Assuming a year is 365 days, it is simply a matter of multiplication:

```
round(365*.08493150685)
```

For a leap year, this number is 366.

Answer (score 1):

Proportion:

```
0.084 : 1 = x : 365
```

Solve for x.